# Error in snapshot listener: FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a Firestore database on Google Firebase with "village" collection inside of it.
I want to limit read/write functionality for each document for specific user with their uuid as the document key.

I have added the rule to the "Rules" tab in Firestore, but I'm when I'm trying to fetch data I get an error saying that I don't have permisions to the Firestore...

[image: Village collection]
[image: Document/user uuid]

This is my rule:

```
 rules_version = '2';
    service cloud.firestore {
      match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /village/{villageId} {
            allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == villageId;
            }
      }
    }
```

This is the code snippet which returns data successfully if I remove my rule from Firestore:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const collectionRef = collection(db, "village");
    const q = query(collectionRef, orderBy("timestamp", "desc"));
    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot: any) => {
      setVillage(
        querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
          ...doc.data(),
          id: doc.id,
          timestamp: doc.data().timestamp?.toDate().getTime(),
        }))
      );
    });
    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);
```

This is the console.log
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current query is requesting all villages, and ordering them by their timestamp. Because your user can only access their own village, you need to change your query to only target what they have access to (remember that Firestore Security Rules [are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#rules_are_not_filters)).

To update your code to work with the rules you defined, you need to switch from a query of all villages, to just their village.

```
const currentUser = ...;

useEffect(
  () => {
    if (!currentUser) return; // signed out

    const villageDocRef = doc(db, "village", auth.currentUser.uid);

    return onSnapshot(
      villageDocRef,
      {
        next: (docSnapshot) => { // don't use the any type
          if (!docSnapshot.exists()) { // don't forget to handle missing data
            return setVillage(null);
          }
          docData = docSnapshot.data();
          setVillage({
            ...docData,
            id: docSnapshot.id,
            timestamp: docData.timestamp?.toMillis() // shorter than .toDate().getTime()
          });
        },
        error: (err) => {
          // TODO: Handle Firestore errors
          console.error('Failed to get village data ', err);
          setVillage(null);
        }
      }
    );
  },
  [currentUser] // rerun when user changes
);
```

Comment: So the plan is to create a query which only queries specific document and then also I need to write Firestore rules to protect myself ?

Comment: @florjank Because Firestore is a serverless database, the security rules are how you prevent users reading/writing data that isn't theirs. When you write a query, if it would return any documents that the user doesn't have access to, the entire query is rejected with the insufficient permissions error. So you tweak the query so that any documents that match your query are accessible by the user. You could adapt the query to be `query(collectionRef, orderBy(documentId(), "desc"), orderBy("timestamp", "desc"), where(documentId(), "==", currentUser.uid))`, but using the doc ref is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

May it help someone, in my case the same error occurred because in Firestore rules I had `request.time < timestamp.date(2022, 8, 6);` Changing the date to a later point in time solved my issue.